# Undefined function or method 'cornermetric' for input arguments of type 'logical'

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

i m trying to find corners in an image. I m using matlab 7.6 version and facing this error.

here is code

k='coins1.png';
i=imread(k);
im=im(1:150,1:120);
c=cornermetric(im);

Answer (score 1):

You need [Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/image/) to use this function. Type `ver` in MATLAB to check.